# pattern.en Unresolved import

Tags: python, python-2.7, pydev

I used `pip install pattern` to pattern in my virtualenv (python 2.7). It was installed with following message:  `Successfully uninstalled Pattern-2.6`. When I try to import it in my PyDev project in Eclipse as `import pattern`, it works fine. But if I try to import `en` package as `import pattern.en`, it shows me unresolved import

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the static analyzer doesn't know that the `pattern` lib actually changes the path at runtime so that `pattern.text.en` becomes `pattern.en`.

The related code is:

```
try: 
    __path__.append(os.path.join(__path__[0], "text"))
except:
    pass
```

The workaround is actually doing `import pattern.text.en` or adding `pattern.en` to the `forced builtins` as explained in: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#PyDevInterpreterConfiguration-ForcedBuiltins

Answer (score 2):

Import the library as:

```
from pattern.text.en import suggest
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
After running `pip install pattern` getting **mysql_config: not found** error

Try installing **pattern** by following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pattern
```